# Laptop with Windows 10 and normal keyboard

Tags: laptop

I am looking for a laptop

- Windows 10 Pro, I don't want Windows 11
- At least 15" screen
- Normal keyboard,
- F1-F12 should work without pressing another key
- home, end, pageup, pagedn, ins and del should also work without pressing anything else
- Not a fan of key engravings lit - they are either not visible or too bright
- Dont need power guzzling touch screen
- I want to attach a second screen via UBS or HDMI
- Min 16GB ram
- Min 1TB HDD
- Preferably under $2000US
- Open to Mac running windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some minor details that I will be assuming when writing this answer:

There are no good laptops with HDD booting anymore, so I will assume an SSD is also ok. Windows is currently also only Windows 11 on new laptops but you can still install Windows 10 on most of them.

The one I would reccomend is the Framework 16 DIY. If you spec it out with 2x8GB RAM and a 1TB SSD, you would come out a little under $2000. For that kinda money you are getting an ultra repairable laptop (I have the Framework 13 and I have heared that the 16 is even better) with a Ryzen 7 7840HS and later the possibility for a GPU. You can connect up to 3 external displays if I'm correct (although you could technically have 6 HDMI ports but that's just stupid). The only downside is is that it has a backlit keyboard but I think you can turn it off. There is no option to buy a Windows 10 license (thanks Microsoft) but you can still install Windows 10 and then buy it later in the Microsoft store

Comment: I had a look, it seems that the display is only 13.5".  Did you think therwise ?

Comment: The Framework 16 DIY isn't available yet, it's in pre-order. The only Framework laptop available to buy today is the 13" one like OP saw.

Comment: @Romen, I knew it was preorder.  I can wait.  The reason I am trying to buy a new one is because I want a larger screen than what I have now.  And 13" is too small.

Comment: The Framework 13 is indeed pretty small (which is the one I have) but the Framework 16 is 16in

Comment: @Irsu85, Could you point me to a page on their website.  I went through the process of building it up and just before ordering, decided it check the screen size.  The only reference I found was 13"

Comment: https://frame.work/be/en/products/laptop16-diy-amd-7040

That's for my region but it should also be availible for your region

Comment: I had seen that page, but it doesnt mention screen size.  So, I have fired an email to them.